# Is there any way json_decode can return a type that is not an array or null if $assoc is set to true?

Tags: php

I am using php's json_decode to decode some json, but i've been getting a /var/log/apache/error_log:PHP Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

```
$data = json_decode($this->body, true);
if (is_null($data))
{
    throw new Exception(...);
}
...
$foo = $data['foo']['bar']; // this line causes the fatal error
...
```

Based on some research, the only way that can cause the error is if $data is a string. but since json_decode with $assoc = to true seems to guarantee null or an array, that should not be the case. Can anyone think of any way how that code could possibly cause an error?

Comment: also look at `isset()`. chances are foo isn't an array.

Comment: `if($data === false) { 
var_dump(json_last_error());
}`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: `$data` can be `=== false` without a decoding error if `$this->body` contains the string `false`, which is decoded to a native PHP boolean false value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `json_decode` can return other types, and `$assoc` has nothing to do with it.

```
$a = json_encode('foobar'); // returned JSON: "foobar"
$b = json_decode($a, true); // $b is a string

$a = json_encode(true); // returned JSON: true
$b = json_decode($a, true); // $b is a boolean
```

`$assoc = true` only means that *objects* (associative arrays) in the JSON will be decoded as PHP associative arrays, while the default is to decode them as PHP objects. It does not affect any other type of data in the JSON, so if your root JSON element is not an array, the `json_decode` will return non-array too.

Comment: Thank you. This was the cause of my problem!